# JUnit, JMock, JUnitRuleMockery: what am I missing

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, gradle, jmock

This is strange: I am using `JUnit` with `JMock` using the `Rule` [JUnitRuleMockery](http://jmock.org/javadoc/jmock-2.6.0/doc/org/jmock/integration/junit4/JUnitRuleMockery.html) for a while and it always worked perfectly fine: expectations where checked at the end of the test and if one (or more) was missing the test was failing. However, this snippet is not working for me in Eclipse (`DAO` is the interface described in `org.mongodb.morphia.dao.DAO`):

```
  @Rule public JUnitRuleMockery context = new JUnitRuleMockery();

  private DAO<Cobrand, ObjectId> dao = context.mock(DAO.class);
  private final Retriever service = new Retriever(dao);

  @Test
  public void canRetrieveASinglePropertyValue () throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException
  {
    context.checking(new Expectations()
    {
      {
        oneOf(dao).findOne("cobrand", "cobrandName"); will(returnValue(prepareFakeCobrand("cobrandName")));
        oneOf(dao).findOne("cobrand", "cobrandName"); will(returnValue(prepareFakeCobrand("cobrandName")));
      }
    });

    String value = service.getValue("cobrandName", "property");

    assertThat(value, equalTo("value"));

    //context.assertIsSatisfied();
  }
```

When I say "not working" I mean that I have to uncomment the line `context.assertIsSatisfied();` to see the test failing (when in Eclipse I run this class as a Junit test). For completeness, this is the code `service.getValue`, where `findOne` is clearly called only once:

```
public String getValue (String cobrandName, String property)
{
  Cobrand cobrand = cobrandDAO.findOne("cobrand", cobrandName);
  return "value";
}
```

I am using `Gradle` to manage my build, and if I execute the command `gradle clean test`, with the line `context.assertIsSatisfied();` commented, the test fails. Here my `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  def hamcrestVersion = "1.3"
  def jmockVersion = "2.6.0"

  compile 'org.mongodb.morphia:morphia:0.106'

  testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:${hamcrestVersion}"
  testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:${hamcrestVersion}"
  testCompile "org.jmock:jmock:${jmockVersion}"
  testCompile "org.jmock:jmock-junit4:${jmockVersion}"
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to check why `Run As` -> `JUnit test` in Eclipse is not behaving as expected while the same code works (the test fails) when executed via `gradle clean test`?

Comment: Check your Eclipse build path an make sure you have the same dependencies there as you build.gradle file.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't look to be the problem. Check http://s25.postimg.org/luflrf533/eclipse_path.png and http://s25.postimg.org/9v43k3zi7/eclipse_path_2.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem.
The issue did was related to classpath as [jeremyjjbrown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/914763/jeremyjjbrown) suggested in his comment, but was related to the [Eclipse-Gradle plugin](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/) and the way it imports projects.
<s>**How I solved the problem**</s>

1. deleted the project in Eclipse
2. went to terminal, in the project source folder
3. typed `gradle cleanEclipse`
4. typed `gradle eclipse`
5. in Eclipse, import the project following the `Import` -> `Existing Projects into Workspace`

That indeed solved the problem, but then I could not manage Gradle directly inside Eclipse (i.e. I could not `right click` -> `Gradle` -> `Refresh All`) since the project did not have a Gradle nature. Converting it to a Gradle project made the original problem coming back. So, finally, 
**How I really solved the problem**
Looking at my `gradle.build`, you can see `testCompile "org.jmock:jmock-junit4:2.6.0"`. jMock has a subtle problem: it brings `junit-dep:4.4` with it. That dependency in Eclipse was causing the problem, inserting the related jar into the classpath. Changing the `testCompile` line to

```
testCompile ("org.jmock:jmock-junit4:${jmockVersion}") {
  exclude group:"junit"
}
```

really solved the problem.

I thank [pbanfi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/278124/pbanfi) who personally helped my debugging and solving the problem for real